# How can I force https for swaggers Request URLs?

Tags: c#, https, swagger, swagger-ui

I first ran into this issue when i was trying to solve how to force swagger ui to search for my `swagger/docs/v1` using `https`. I managed to solve that using this function in the `SwaggerConfig.cs`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
       c.RootUrl(ResolveBasePath)

        .
        .
        .


        string ResolveBasePath(HttpRequestMessage message)
        {
            var virtualPathRoot = message.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot;
            var schemeAndHost = "https://" + message.RequestUri.Host;
            return new Uri(new Uri(schemeAndHost, UriKind.Absolute), virtualPathRoot).AbsoluteUri;
        }
```

That successfully searches for the documents and displays them on the swagger UI. When i actually try to test one of my API calls, it uses `http` and the request fails. I've already used `c.Schemes(new[] {"https"});` in an attempt to do this, with no success. I would greatly appreciate if anyone has some insight into how i might solve this.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up figuring out the issue. For some reason, it built a previous version that included `http` in the scheme.